# Optimize SQL query in form of a Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, performance, tuning, performance-tuning

I have a Oracle SQL query with multiple "IN" statements. It takes around a minute to execute in an average.

My task is to optimize this query in form of PL/SQL procedure so that the user gets the output resultset as a ref cursor.

Please suggest. Thanks!

**SQL Query:**

```
select sp.column1, sp.column2,sp.column3,gen.column1,nvl(gen.column2,0)+nvl(gen.column3,0) GENSIZE,gen.column4,gen.column5 
from table1 sp,
(select * from table2 where table2.column1 in (
select table1.column4 from table1 where table1.column2 in (
select table3.column1 from table3 where table3.column2='124578'))) gen
where gen.id=sp.id;
```

Comment: Could you provide the execution plan for this query?

Comment: Using PL/SQL will slow down things a little (perhaps unnoticably).  It will certainly not improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as returning a ref cursor the following should work;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_table1_data(p_column2 IN table3.column2%TYPE, 
                                            p_tables_recs  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) AS
BEGIN

   OPEN p_table_recs FOR 
      SELECT sp.column1
           , sp.column2
           , sp.column3
           , gen.column1
           , NVL(gen.column2, 0) + NVL(gen.column3, 0) gensize
           , gen.column4
           , gen.column5
      FROM   table1 sp
          , (SELECT *
             FROM   table2
             WHERE  table2.column1 IN (SELECT table1.column4
                                       FROM   table1
                                       WHERE  table1.column2 IN (SELECT table3.column1
                                                                 FROM   table3
                                                                 WHERE  table3.column2 = p_column_2))) gen
       WHERE  gen.id = sp.id;
END get_table1_data;
```

Comment: I did the same and as suspected, using procedure to execute the same query has reduced the performance even more. Probably the main modification I have to make is to optimize the SQL by removing nested "IN" clauses and use something else instead like GLOBAL TEMPORARY tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will become a simple `INNER JOIN` chain, as follow:

Pay attention: instead gen alias I've used `____` because I don't know from which table you want to take the value.

So you can change every `____` with correct alias table.

```
SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, t1.column3, ____.column1,
       nvl(____.column2,0) + nvl(____.column3,0) GENSIZE,
       ____.column4, ____.column5 
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.column4 = t2.column1
JOIN table3 t3
    ON t3.column1 = t1.column2
WHERE t3.column2 = '1234578'
AND t1.id = ___.id
```

Comment: Hi Joe. Thanks for your response. But it's taking way more time than the previous query. That's why I want to use PL/SQL instead of SQL.

Comment: @SnehilKandpal: Have you add index on involved fields?

Comment: Yes I have. This was the first thing I reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have indexes on table2.id, table1.column4, table3.column1. This may have more influence than working with a ref cursor.